# Cube edges squished?

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I printed a test cube with ABS on my Ender 3 and after some tuning, I still have a problem I cannot solve. Two of the vertical edges (I believe they are the ones on the X+ side) are slightly squished in. Could this be due to warping or something else? I printed it at 0.1 mm layer height, 235/110 °C hotend/bed temperatures.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: please proide the following to allow better help: Your print material (PLA? ABS?), your print speed & a screen capture of the model in your slice in layer view, about at the half poin.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely to your print you will see that the edges are part of the problem, e.g. you also have a problem called "Elephant foot" where the base shows a fairing to the build plate.

The elephant foot deficiency is caused by an imbalanced choice of bed and hotend temperature and print cooling. This imbalance also causes the edges to collapse (probably also caused by the infill, or lack of it).

You should look into finding a better printing temperature combo and experiment with little cooling. This will also help you to better print the rest of the cube.

Answer (score 1):

The warping you see is caused by uneven cooling of the part as it's printed: the printbed keeps the bottom warm, while the middle cools, and the top is still warm from printing.  The fix for this is to place the printer in an enclosure to prevent drafts and raise the air temperature.

People have used all sorts of things as printer enclosures: everything from foil-lined cardboard boxes heated by the printbed, to fancy metal-and-glass constructions with active temperature control.